# DateTime conversion adds one extra hour

Tags: c#, date, datetime, timezone

I have an input time in UTC and want to convert it to the device's local time. I want to use the TryParse method to avoid exceptions.

The input time is 7 PM. Expected `out DateTime date` parameter is 20:00. Instead it becomes 21:00.

My time zone is GMT+1 Central European Time. It is not currently DST, but DST starts later this March.

```
var value = "4/2/2018 7:00:00 PM"; // UTC time

if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out DateTime date))
{
    var isDST = date.IsDaylightSavingTime(); // true
    var kind = date.Kind; // DateTimeKind.Local
    var time = date.ToShortTimeString(); // 21:00
}
```

Comment: `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal`

Comment: With `AssumeLocal` in place of `AssumeUniversal` the time becomes 19:00 except `convLocalTime` becomes 21:00.

Comment: What timezone is `value` supposed to be? Local or UTC? and are you observing daylight savings time?

Comment: How do you suggest I observe daylight savings time? I have not done anything with DST.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your timezone (not just offset)

Comment: Ideally, specify what `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` shows and give us more information about how you're running this code.

Comment: It depends on what you want to convert that UTC date to. If it's local time, use  `(...)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal(...)` since you have an UTC date as reference.

Comment: @javm what timezone is the device set to? I am not asking about +/- hours but the country/state name. You're saying ***it starts later this month***, 2nd of April would be inside DST, and if your timezone changes from +1 to +2 during DST then the code is working correctly.

Comment: @javm see, [it is correct](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20180402T190000&p1=1440&p2=tz_cet&p3=tz_cest). 2018-04-02T19:00:00UTC would be 21:00 because _on that day_ your local timezone will be +2 instead of +1.

Comment: "4/2/2018" is April 2, so it falls into DST which starts in the end of march. So the output is correct, because UTC 7 PM is your timezone 9 PM (1 hour regular offset + 1 hour DST offset) on that date.

Comment: That's a good observation! Now I'm trying to do the conversion without consideration for DST.

Comment: @javm: *Why* would you want it want it without DST being taken into account? You talk about "It is not currently DST" as if that matters for your conversion. Using the current UTC offset for a later date is a very odd thing to do in my experience. If it were currently June and you were trying to convert a December timestamp, would you want that to include DST, or do you *never* want to use DST? The right code to use would depend on the answers to all of these questions - but I would take a step back and think about whether you *really* want to use a local time that won't actually be correct.

Comment: If the output is now as you expected, and your comment of "I'm trying to do the conversion without consideration for DST" is obsolete, I'd suggest deleting the question entirely. If not, you should definitely edit it to clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The database field stores the datetime converted to UTC, so I have to convert the time zone to where the app is in use.

Comment: If @SalmanA posts the answer I can accept it. I could not delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework will honor the daylight saving time rules. In your example:

- The input is `April 2, 2018 7:00 PM UTC`
- The timezone for output is `Central European Time (CET)`

Apparently your country<sup>1</sup> is scheduled to use `Central European Summer Time (CEST)` on last Sunday of March and the timezone offset changes `+01:00` to `+02:00`. The result `April 2, 2018 9:00 PM` [is therefore correct](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20180402T190000&p1=1440&p2=tz_cet&p3=tz_cest)<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> A country or subdivision defines its timezone which includes one or more offsets and the dates on which those offsets are effective.
<sup>2</sup> The same code will produce one hour difference if the input date is outside DST.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't consider daylight saving time.

```
bool isDST = time.IsDaylightSavingTime;
```

to check if DST is in effect for specific date.

Comment: The value of `IsDaylightSavingTime()` is `true`. How can I make sure the conversion takes height of this value?

Comment: The OP shouldn't need to do that. Either .NET is converting it from UTC to local, including DST, or it's not - the OP shouldn't need to do anything with that explicitly.

Comment: @javm: You shouldn't need to make a change in your code, but that does suggest that your idea of your time zone and the system's idea of your time zone aren't the same. Please provide more information about your system's time zone in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't agree. OP clearly wants local datetime without DST, reasons are beyond our business. While i understand why i got downvoted, at the same time its not clear to me how can he get expected datetime without manual modifications.

Comment: @Creo: The comment from 39 minutes ago appears to indicate that, but there was no indication *before* that comment. I'll remove my downvote, but I think you should expand the answer very significantly before it deserves any upvotes - and to do that, we'd need more information from the OP about their (odd-sounding so far) requirements.

Comment: And actually, the OP's edit suggests "the output is correct" anyway. (And if the OP always wants to apply the time zone's standard offset, that would most simply be achieved without the code you've shown, but by using `TimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset`.)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `Local` date time kind, because it means your code would run differently depending on the time zone of the machine it is being run.

You need to make sure you have a valid date time representation in UTC and then explicitly convert to the timezone you need:

```
var utcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(val), DateTimeKind.Utc); // guarantee your DateTime is in Utc.

TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. Europe Standard Time");
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, localZone));
```

Comment: "Avoid using Local date time kind, because it means your code would run differently depending on the time zone of the machine it is being run." That's the whole idea in this case: the OP wants to convert a UTC value into a local representation. That's entirely reasonable to display a value to a user. It's also entirely reasonable for the OP to specify the expected kind in the parse operation... I'd trust that significantly more than calling `DateTime.Parse` and leaving it implicit, then using `DateTime.SpecifyKind`.